# Real Projective Space

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, general-topology, differential-geometry, manifolds

> **Corollary $\bf7.15.$** *The real projective space $\mathbb{R}P^n$ is second countable.*

How I can prove this corollary 7.15.I consider that ı can apply the corollary 7.10.But I could not can you help me.

> **Corollary $\bf7.10.$** *If $\,\sim\,$ is an open equivalence relation on a second-countable space $S$, then the quotient space $S/\sim$ is second countable.*

Comment: Well, what have you tried?

Comment: By open relation, do you mean the quotient map is open?

Answer (score 2):

Recall that $S^n\subset\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ is second countable as it is a subspace of a second countable space. Can you see how to use your corollary 7.10, along with this fact to show that $\mathbb{R}P^n$ is second countable?